# Getting Howard Hinnant's short_alloc (C++11 version) to compile in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, memory, allocation

I'd like to be able to use a custom allocator with std::vector so that small data buffers (say, less than 1024 bytes) are stored on the stack, and only longer vectors are stored on the heap. As one who has a background in Fortran, it causes me physical pain each time I have to do a heap memory allocation to store half-a-dozen elements for the duration of a five-line subroutine!

Howard Hinnant has published his [short_alloc](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) allocator which does exactly what I'm looking for, and if I compile it with gcc it works a treat. However, in Visual C++ I can't get it to compile. In Visual C++ 2013 part of the problem was that that too many C++11 keywords were unsupported, but I still came up against a problem even when I had #DEFINE'd all of these away. Today I tried compiling in Visual C++ 2015 CTP 5, and the keywords are now all supported but the compilation ultimately fails for the same reason.

The problem is this: for a reason I can't claim to understand fully, Hinnant's code defaults the copy constructor but deletes the copy assignment operator:

```
short_alloc(const short_alloc&) = default;
short_alloc& operator=(const short_alloc&) = delete;
```

When attempting to compile, this triggers the following error in Visual C++:

```
xmemory0(892): error C2280: 'short_alloc<int,1024> &short_alloc<1024>::operator =(const short_alloc<1024> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

What confuses me even more is that if I modify Hinnant's code to say

```
short_alloc(const short_alloc&) = default;
short_alloc& operator=(const short_alloc&) = default;
```

...then I still obtain *exactly* the same error message.

For reference, here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "short_alloc.h"

void populate_the_vector(std::vector<int, short_alloc<int, 1024> > &theVector)
{
    arena<1024> B;
    std::vector<int, short_alloc<int, 1024> > anothertestvec{(short_alloc<int, 1024>(B))};
    anothertestvec.resize(10);
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        anothertestvec[i] = i;
    }    
    theVector = std::move(anothertestvec);  // Actually causes a copy, as the Arenas are different
}

int main()
{
    arena<1024> A;
    std::vector<int, short_alloc<int, 1024> > testvec{(short_alloc<int, 1024>(A))};
    populate_the_vector(testvec);
    printf("Testvec(10)=%d\r\n", testvec[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error goes away if I comment-out the line saying

```
theVector = std::move(anothertestvec);
```

so obviously the underlying problem is that Visual C++ approaches the copy in a different way from gcc. Even so, I'm at a loss for how to proceed from here. Is there a way to get this to work in Visual C++?

Comment: That assignment operator is probably unavailable for the base class (edit: or for a member), and hence generating the default implementation also results in a delete.

Comment: @Mehrdad There's no base class, but it has a reference member.

Comment: @T.C.: Or that, yeah. I didn't really think through which one it might be.

Comment: Also, for the record, I *think* the code in `pointer_in_buffer` relies on Undefined Behavior, and in fact probably *cannot* be implemented without invoking UB.

Comment: @Mehrdad unspecified, not undefined. It can also be implemented without unspecified behavior with a loop that tests the pointer for equality with `buf`, `buf + 1`, ... , `buf + N`, but that would be a massive loss in performance unless the optimizer is clever enough.

Comment: Back to the original question, `allocator_traits<short_alloc<...>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is supposed to be `false_type` by default, so move assignment of the `vector` isn't supposed to move assign the allocator. Something is broken in MSVC's `vector` or its `allocator_traits`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest hack that I can think of is replacing

```
short_alloc& operator=(const short_alloc&) = delete;
```

with

```
short_alloc& operator=(const short_alloc&) 
{ 
    assert(false && "this should never be called"); 
    return *this; 
};
```

It looks like a pretty dangerous hack, but it's actually not that bad in this particular case, and here's why:

The reason the original version doesn't compile in VC++ is that its standard library implementation of `std::vector`'s move assignment operator makes the classic mistake of testing `std::allocator_traits<...>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` using an `if()` statement.

It does the proper check and doesn't assign the allocator if the trait value is `false` (and moves the elements individually to the other side if the allocators are different, as requested by the standard), but the code on the `if()` branch still has to compile, even though it will never be reached for this type of allocator.

So, that assignment operator will never be called by the container's implementation at runtime, and that's why the hack is safe in this particular case.

(The funniest thing is that, one line below that `if()`, the actual moving is implemented properly with a helper function using tag dispatch...)

---

This is based on the standard library implementation that comes with Visual C++ 2013 Update 4.

Update: As reported by the OP in the comments, VC14 CTP5 has the same problem.

---

Update 2: As indicated in the comments for the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1114355/the-stl-should-handle-allocators-that-arent-assignable), the fix for this issue will be available in the final version of Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: Thank you, that works in VC14 CTP 5 and gives the desired behaviour.

Comment: @EosPengwern Could you double-check in the sources for the CTP if that `if()` is still there, just to be sure? Also, this bug should be reported. Do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: I can't see any difference at all between the relevant parts of the VC\include\vector in VC12 and VC14, so it looks like the same bug is present. I have an MSDN support subscription, so I can report it myself. Thank you again for your help with this.

Comment: I agree this is a bug; thanks for [reporting this issue on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1114355).